# Asp.Net MVC AllowHtml attribute fails on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having troubles trying to use a rich text editor in Asp.Net MVC.

Actually I have the field that contains the RTF marked with the `[AllowHtml]` attribute and it's working right in the model binder, so I get the html value in the post method of the action.

But then, while rendering the response, in the layout page we access another property of the request directly using `ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Params["paramname"]` and there it throws an `HttpRequestValidationException` because of the value of the text field, even if it's not the form parameter we are trying to access.

Any clue about how to avoid this?

Comment: You could follow the MVC pattern, add the value you need to the model, and have the view know nothing about the "request". Doesn't directly solve the problem, but it should eliminate the issue.

Comment: No i can't, it's a layout and doesn't have a model, also it's a generic code that allows for opening pages as modals that it's working perfect at the moment. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Why would you by-pass MVC model binding?

Comment: Crazy specification; i have to post multiple views related to different components (it's a modular application) from a single submit button and it have to work without JS...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Request.Unvalidated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.unvalidated.aspx) property to get the value without triggering validation.

Comment: Thanks a lot! in that case won't be a security issue also so that's it.